# Add value to an array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new in coding, so be patient please. I've made an array that looks like this:

```js
var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];

function printit(number) {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = minArray[number];
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" value="" id="number" />
  <input type="button" value="Word is:" onclick="printit(number)" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="test" />
```

And I'd like to write in a number in the text field and then get that specific word from the array. So if I were to write 1 and then press print, the outcome would be: Hi.

Anyone that can nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: A first mistake : you create `minArray` but then reference `myArray` in the `printit` function.

Answer (score 6):

You are not getting the value of the input correctly. You have two options, both documented below.

To get the value of the input you need to do the following:

```
document.getElementById('number').value;
```

You also called your array `myArray` and `minArray`.

See full code example below.

```js
var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];

function printit() {
  const number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = minArray[number];
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" id="number" />
  <input type="button" value="Word is:" onclick="printit()" />
</form>
</br>
<div id="test" />
```

You could also pass the event to the input `onclick` function and get the `value` from this. You will also have to convert the string to an integer using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];

function printit(event) {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = minArray[parseInt(number.value)];
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" id="number" />
  <input type="button" value="Word is:" onclick="printit(event)" />
</form>
</br>
<div id="test" />
```

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald We can directly get value of input box by using number.value. Don't have to do document getelementbyid again.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

HTML elements with ids are global variable. So you can directly refer to input box by using `number` variable.
So in your code if you use `number.value` it will give you value of input box.

```js
var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];

function printit() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = minArray[number.value];
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <input type="text" value="" id="number" />
  <input type="button" value="Word is:" onclick="printit(number)" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];
 
 function printit()
 {
   var index=parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
   
   if(index>=minArray.length){
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML ="Not Found";
   }
   else{
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = minArray[index];
   
   }
  
 }
```

```html
<form name="f1">
     <input type="text" value="" id="number"/>
    <input type="button" value="Word is:"  onclick="printit()"/>
</form>
<br/>
<div id="test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];
function printit() {
 var a=document.getElementById('number').value
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = minArray[a-1];
}

<form name="f1">
    <input type="text" value="" id="number"/>
    <input type="button" value="Word is:" onclick="printit()"/>
    </form>
 <div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code changes

```
   <script>
      var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];
      function printit()
      {
          var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =minArray[number];
      }
   </script>


  <form name="f1">
       <input type="text" value="" id="number"/>
       <input type="button" value="Word is:" onclick="printit()"/>
  </form>
     </br>
  <div id="test"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply get value like this:

```
var valueOfArray = minArray[1];
```

or if you are going to store that writen value into a variable:

```
var valueOfArray = minArray[storedNumber];
```

then you can pass it to the html:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = valueOfArray;
```

Also is a good practice to insure that storedNumber is really a number, then parse it and check if is a number:

```js
var minArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Yes", "No", "Good"];
function printit() {
  var storedNumber = document.getElementById('number').value;
  storedNumber = parseInt(storedNumber);
  if (!isNaN(storedNumber)){
    var valueOfArray = minArray[storedNumber];
    if (typeof valueOfArray != 'undefined'){
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = valueOfArray; 
    }else{
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= "Number is not valid";
    }
  }else{
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= "NaN";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
     <input type="text" value="" id="number"/>
    <input type="button" value="Word is:"  onclick="printit()"/>
</form>
<br/>
<div id="test"/>
```

AND of course, adjust your array name when printing, you are using it as `MyArray`, but the correct name is `minArray`